# purpose of uninsured/under insured coverage

Tags: united-states, insurance, car-insurance

If one has comprehensive coverage along with Liability ( Bodily and property), so why does one may need uninsured/under insured coverage for vehicle insurance if he already has Collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some states require you to have uninsured motorist property damage insurance, so depending on your state you could just need it regardless of whether you'd otherwise benefit from it.

Uninsured/Underinsured coverage helps in cases of hit/run and in cases when the at-fault party is uninsured/underinsured. Collision also covers those instances, but typically does so with higher premiums/deductibles than uninsured/underinsured coverage.

My agent advocates going with a higher deductible on my collision to keep premiums low and keeping uninsured/underinsured insurance on the policy. So if I'm at fault I have to shell out a bit more, but if I'm not at fault there's very little out of pocket expense for me. This feels like a good balance to me. If you're already shelling out for a low deductible, it might not be worth adding uninsured/underinsured.